# Execute query into UDF BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a function that returns a value of a select, is this possible? for example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION returnSelect(orden INT64) AS (
  (SELECT ID FROM TABLE ID LIMIT 1)
);
```

thanks

Comment: what is your use case? please provide more details so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `UDF` like that by wrapping your query with additional parentheses. In your case, as you don't use the parameter `orden`, you can do:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION returnSelect() AS (
  (SELECT ID FROM TABLE ID LIMIT 1)
);
```

And then call it:

```
SELECT returnSelect()
```

I hope it helps